# Phonegap WebSql database table creation gets fail

Tags: html, cordova, web-sql

When below Sample code of Phonegap app is executed in iPad, table gets created as well as records get inserted. But as soon as it navigates to next page using "window.location = 'main.html'" table disappears/delete. Some time it works properly and all records get displayed on main.html. Sample code:

```
db.transaction(function (transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql('drop table if exists categoryType', null, function () {
         transaction.executeSql('create table if not exists categoryType(id text primary key, code text, name text)', null, function () {
               for (var i = 0; i < category_types.length; i++) 
               {
                     var insert_count = 0;
                      transaction.executeSql('insert into categoryType(id, code, name)  values(?,?,?)', [category_types[i].id, category_types[i].code , category_types[i].name],
                      function()
                      {
                          insert_count++;
                          if ( insert_count == category_types.length)
                             window.location = "main.html";
                      });
               }
           });
   });
});
```

If we add timeout in above code before navigating to main.html page issue gets resolved.
Sample code with timeout:

```
db.transaction(function (transaction) {
  transaction.executeSql('drop table if exists categoryType', null, function () {
         transaction.executeSql('create table if not exists categoryType(id text primary key, code text, name text)', null, function () {
               for (var i = 0; i < category_types.length; i++) 
               {
                      var insert_count = 0;
                      transaction.executeSql('insert into categoryType(id, code, name)  values(?,?,?)', [category_types[i].id, category_types[i].code , category_types[i].name],
                      function()
                      {
                          insert_count++;
                          if ( insert_count == category_types.length)
                          {
                               setTimeout(function() {
                                   window.location = "main.html";
                               }, 5000);
                          }
                      });
                }
           });
   });

});
```

I can run the code successfully using a timeout, but I don't want to depend on arbitrary timeout period.  Earlier the same code was working properly but now it is causing issue recently. Is there any solution??